# CASE, IFElse, or SWITCH Powershell to change output of Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, if-statement, switch-statement, case, invoke

I have the following code that works as a stand-alone query:

```
$Type = (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer })

    switch -regex ($Type) 
    { 
        "VMw.+" {"VM"} 
        default {"Physical"}
    }
```

I want to add the switch command within the Invoke command instead of a variable (dropping the $Type variable) so that it can be run against multiple computers, how can this be accomplished, I am not determined to use Switch to accomplish the end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-WmiObject` has a `ComputerName` property so you don't need to use `Invoke-Command`

```
switch -regex (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer)
{ 
    "VMw.+" {"VM"} 
    default {"Physical"}
}
```

And by wrapping it in a simple `foreach` loop you can easily run it against multiple computers:

```
$Computers = "computer1","computer3","computer3"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    switch -regex (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer)
    { 
        "VMw.+" {Write-Output "$Computer is a VM Computer"} 
        default {Write-Output "$Computer is a Physical Computer"}
    }
}
```

Comment: That works for me: `code`"Type" = switch -regex (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer)
        { 
            "VMw.+" {Write-Output "VM"} 
            default {Write-Output "Physical"}
        }